# fetching blob data from sybase

Tags: c++, database, sybase

my question is about sybase's ct_get_data() function
i got below message when fetching TEXT data that is is not the last column of the result set.

```
Open Client Message:
Message number: LAYER = (1) ORIGIN = (1) SEVERITY = (1) NUMBER = (61)
Message String: ct_get_data(): user api layer: external error: Item of 1 is not greater than the largest item bound.
```

how can i resolve this situation?

PS: i searched web and found a similar situation but doesnt resolve the case. pls see the link

http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:LRG0396HfJoJ:cookp.com/thread/950711/ct_get_data()%2520fails+Item+of+%251!%22+is+not+greater+than+the+largest+item+bound.%22&hl=tr&client=firefox-a&gl=tr&strip=1

Answer (score 1):

The text column has to be the last column in the select [Sybase doc on ct_get_data](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sdk_12.5.1.ctref/html/ctref/X53057.htm) which is effectively what the referred URL says